# Why does my console turn off when picking up the Ender Dragon's egg?

Tags: ps3, minecraft-legacy-console

I killed the Ender Dragon, and proceeded to collect the egg. After collecting it safely with a piston, I went through the portal back to the Overworld. After the credits my game glitched and the PS3 turned off unexpectedly.

What is happening to my game?

Comment: My power did not go out!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is this a one off event or keeps re-occurring?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your PS3 overheated. Make sure that you are not stacking many things on top of your PS3 and that it has enough space to vent.

Comment: I have nothing on it

Comment: It still could have overheated if the room is hot enough, or if it does not have a decent amount of space to vent.

Comment: As a general tip: avoid putting it in a closed cupboard, it needs to have airflow to keep cool. Also try and avoid putting it on a carpet or rug, as that absorbs the heat and can be harder for it to maintain a cooler temp.

Comment: @user139268 - to add to TreeHouseFalcon's answer/comments, you can also try blowing out/cleaning the fan/vent areas and getting any dust out. That will help it cool down more effectively.